# Why does one of my two slices panic with "runtime error: index out of range"?

Tags: go, runtime-error, indexoutofrangeexception, panic

```
func main() {
        str1 := make([]string, 10)
        str2 := []string{}
        fmt.Println(str1[0]) *No error*
        fmt.Println(str2[0]) *error*
    }
```

Why does `fmt.Println(str2[0])` show an error in Go?

Comment: `str1` is a string slice with length 10, `str2` is an empty slice. when you try to access the first(zero) element of empty slice, it ofc will panic with `index out of range`.

Comment: str 1 is not shows error ,but the str 2 throws panic. actually str1 print like this "" [ ] ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions)
>
> A primary expression of the form
>
> ```
> a[x]
> ```
>
> denotes the element of the array, pointer to array, slice, or string `a` indexed by `x`. The value `x` is called the index,
>
> the index `x` is in range if `0 <= x < len(a)`, otherwise it is out of
>   range

---

`[]string{}` is the same as `make([]string, 0)` Therefore, `0 >= len(str2)` and `str2[0]` is out of range..

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    str1 := make([]string, 10)
    fmt.Println(len(str1), cap(str1), str1)
    str2 := []string{}
    fmt.Println(len(str2), cap(str2), str2)
    fmt.Println(str1[0]) // *No error*
    fmt.Println(str2[0]) // *error*
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/p31fUyb4pqW

Output:

```
10 10 [         ]
0 0 []

panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0
```